# ObjC 2D array: array of array vs linear array vs C array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm implementing a 2D array and concerned about the efficiency of implementation detail, the 2D array interface should provide the two essential methods:

(assume the array is fixed size, specified when creating, so no dynamic size change)

1. getObjectAtRow:Column:
2. setObjectAtRow:Column:
3. enumerateUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger row, NSUInteger column, BOOL *stop)

Implementation:

**Array of arrays (NSMutableArray)**

Having an NSMutableArray of size `rowCount` and each element in it is an NSMutableArray of size `columnCount`, then getter would get the row array then from the row array get the object at specified column, setter would use the same technic. Enumerator uses two enumeration block, one for going through row arrays and for each row array another enumerator for all the objects.

**Linear array (NSMutableArray)**

Having just an NSMutableArray of actual objects, getter and setter would calculate index using:

index = row * columnCount + column;

Enumerator goes through the linear array, and calculate row & column by:

row = index / columnCount
column = index % columnCount

**C array (assume element is struct not class object and size is predefined)**

so I have:

```
MyStruct elements[ROW_COUNT][COLUMN_COUNT]
```

then use it in the usual C way, getter/setter is just getting/setting:

```
elements[row][column]
```

and enumeration is just using two for loops

My concerns:

1. which one is more efficient? I feel like the C array sounds more efficient, but is it a bit hard for memory management especially when using ARC?
2. which one is better? linear array or array of arrays? That is, is it faster to do production/division to get/set object in a linear array, or is it faster by using array of arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest option will be the C array, and if you really care about performance you shouldn't wrap it in an Objective C class, but use a C struct or straight variable instead.

But the easiest, almost-efficient way to do this is to use a 1D `NSMutableArray` and some inline wrapper functions:

```
inline id getObjectAt( NSMutableArray *o, int row, int col ) {
    return [o objectAtIndex: row * MY_FIXED_WIDTH_HERE + col];
}
inline void setObjectAt( NSMutableArray *o, int row, int col, id value ) {
    return [o replaceObjectAtIndex: row * MY_FIXED_WIDTH_HERE + col withObject: value];
}
```

The functions will be inlined, but there's still an objective-c function lookup to perform (`objectAtIndex`/`replaceObjectAtIndex`). Usually that performance hit is negligible; only worry about it if benchmarking shows it is significant.

For implementing a C array: Memory management is easy; just add a loop in the dealloc function to `release` every element, and be careful in the `set` function (retain the new object **then** release the previous object). You'll also need to set up any copying and serialisation/deserialisation functions you might want, and `nil` the items when `init`ing. As for ARC, you can configure it per-file, so just disable it for this object's `.m` file.